# Keep main-sidebar open if hovered over it after scrolling

Tags: jquery

On scrolling, I want to open '.main-sidebar' and when the scrolling has stopped it should close '.main-sidebar'. But if the mouse is over '.main-sidebar' then it needs to stay open.

.sidebar-collapse is a class on the body to collapse or expand the main-sidebar.

I have been at this for some time and I think I need another pair of eyes to spot my errors.

```
// check if the menu is collapsed or not

$('body').on('mousemove', function() {

    var scrollTimer;

    if ($(this).hasClass("sidebar-collapse")) {

        console.log('Check: Menu is collapsed');

        //Scrolling opens menu
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            // detect scrolling and add/remove classes
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll) {
                $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("sidebar-collapse");
            }
            // set and start timer counting for 8 sec
            scrollTimer = setInterval(function() {
                //When time is up addClass back
                $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
            }, 5000);
        });
    } else {

        console.log('Check: Menu Open (missing: .sidebar-collapse)');

        //Stay open if mouse is on menu
        $('.main-sidebar').on('mouseenter', function() {
            if (!$('body').hasClass("sidebar-collapse")) {
                console.log('ON MENU');
                // set and start timer counting for 5 sec
                clearInterval(scrollTimer);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding/removing a class to sidebar on window scroll, and hover on sidebar can be handled with css:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.main-sidebar').addClass("hide", ($(window).scrollTop() > 100));
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.main-sidebar').removeClass('hide');
  }, 1000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jxmL0aer/1/